# No puedo pasar de la rama develop a una rama que ya tengo creada

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de pasar de la rama **develop** con el comando *git checkout #PDC-T112* a una rama que ya tengo creada junto con los cambios que he hecho en la rama develop, pero no me deja y me lanza lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la rama **develop** tengo todos mis cambios y tambien quiero pasarlos a la rama **#PDC-T112**

Answer (score 0):

Debemos mover los cambios en curso en un "stash". Luego puede cambiar de rama y recuperar esos cambios.

```
git stash
git checkout #PDCD-T112
git stash apply
```

[git documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (en inglès)